# &&: cannot use this indirection on type PixelFormat

Tags: .net, opencv, c++-cli

I'm developing a C++/CLI application that uses OpenCV 4.2. In the following code, I'm trying to convert `Bitmap` to a custom type (struct), but it's throwing the following error:

> error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat'

This is my C++ code:

```
typedef struct 
{
    cv::Mat mat;
    System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat pixelFormat;
}CustomImage;


CustomImage BitmapToCustomImage(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bitmap)
{
    CustomImage ob;
    ob.pixelFormat = bitmap->PixelFormat;

    System::Drawing::Rectangle blank = System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height);
    System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bmpdata = bitmap->LockBits(blank, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, bitmap->PixelFormat);

    int wb = ((bitmap->Width * 24 + 31) / 32) * 4;
    cv::Mat cv_img(cv::Size(bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height), CV_8UC3, bmpdata->Scan0.ToPointer(), wb);

    bitmap->UnlockBits(bmpdata);
    ob.mat = cv_img;
    return ob;
} // <------------- the error shows on this line when I compile

System::Drawing::Bitmap^ PerformSomeOperation(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ inputBitmap) 
{
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bitmap;
    CustomImage ob = BitmapToCustomImage(inputBitmap);
    // some stuff
    // try to convert back to bitmap
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here's how I'm passing the bitmap from C#:

```
Bitmap inputImage = (Bitmap)pictureBoxInput.Image;
inputImage = mylibname.PerformSomeOperation(inputImage);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

And is there any other way to pass a bitmap to C++/CLI application apart from sending bitmap handle as that frequently causes issues ?

Comment: C++/CLI is not C++.  Merely an unfortunately named different language.  Like JavaScript and Java.

Comment: I did not downvote.  Anonymous downvoting is a privilege (after a meeting a minimum rep bar) that some members exercise.  The meta-intent is to drive improving the quality of the questions and quality of the answers.  Questions tagged with `c++` (as this one was) get a lot of reviewers in a short span of time.

Comment: Unrelated, but this will blow up the moment you try to access the image once the `BitmapToCustomImage` returns. The way you constructed the `Mat`, it **shares** the pixel buffer (i.e. the buffer needs to exist as long as you use the `Mat` instance). Make a deep copy to avoid that problem.

Comment: @Eljay: It really is not "like Javascript and Java".  C++/CLI is a set of (non-portable) extensions to C++ that take nothing away.  Every valid C++ program is still valid in C++/CLI.

Comment: @DanMašek you're right. It gives `AccessViolationException` when I run the function second time. When I said `frequently causes issues` in the question, I meant that only. Can you please provide an example of how to create a deep copy ?

Comment: [`cv::Mat::clone()`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adff2ea98da45eae0833e73582dd4a660) -- i.e. `ob.mat = cv_img.clone()` and do that before calling `UnlockBits`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to hold a managed type inside a native structure.  C++/CLI does not allow mixed types (it was proposed but never implemented).

Try storing a tracking handle to a boxed PixelFormat

```
struct 
{
    cv::Mat mat;
    gcroot<System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat^> pixelFormat;
} CustomImage;
```

It's a bit weird because PixelFormat is a value type and would not ordinarily be combined with `^`, but the strongly-boxed type is exactly what you want in this particular scenario.

(You also need to solve the lifetime issue for the image buffer, as [Dan points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774803/cannot-use-this-indirection-on-type-pixelformat/60777026#comment107530571_60774803))